# Sorting a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have a np array that is constructed as the intersection of 2 other arrays in the following way:

The first array is:

```
[['! ! !' '! ! ! !']
 ['! ! !' '! ! ! "']
 ['! ! !' '! ! ! .']
 ...,
 ['}' 'was postponed']
 ['}' 'was']
 ['}' '{of']]
```

The second array is:

```
[['! ! !' '! ! ! !']
 ['! ! !' '! ! ! "']
 ['! ! !' '! ! ! .']
 ...,
 ['}' 'was postponed']
 ['}' 'was']
 ['}' '{of']]
```

There are in fact multiple differences between the two arrays, but they occur mainly in the middle rows.

The code used to construct the intersection is:

```
def multidim_intersect(arr1, arr2):
    arr1_view = arr1.view([('',arr1.dtype)]*arr1.shape[1])
    arr2_view = arr2.view([('',arr2.dtype)]*arr2.shape[1])
    intersected = np.intersect1d(arr1_view, arr2_view)
    return intersected.view(arr1.dtype).reshape(-1, arr1.shape[1])
```

The outputted array is:

```
[['!' '!']
 ['!' '! !']
 ['!' '! ! !']
 ...,
 ['}' 'was']
 ['}' 'was postponed']
 ['}' '{of']]
```

As you can see, my new array is sorted differently from the original two arrays (which have multiple exclamation marks sorted before single exclamation marks, as would be done in LC_ALL=C sort). Is there any way to sort my outputted array like my other arrays? Note that the shape of the array is important.

@Mr E arr1 and arr2 were originally lists. I can't give you the exact copy, but I will do my best to construct an example which illustrates what I need.

```
arr1 = [['! ! !' '! ! ! !']
 ['! ! !' '! ! ! "']
 ['! ! !' '! ! ! .']
 ['!' '!']
 ['}' 'was postponed']
 ['}' 'was']
 ['}' '{of']]

arr2 = [['! ! !' '! ! ! !']
 ['! ! !' '! ! ! "']
 ['! ! !' '! ! ! .']
 ['!' '!']
 ['}' 'was postponed']
 ['}' 'was']
 ['}' '{of']]
```

Ideally, the output would be:

```
[['! ! !' '! ! ! !']
 ['! ! !' '! ! ! "']
 ['! ! !' '! ! ! .']
 ['!' '!']
 ['}' 'was postponed']
 ['}' 'was']
 ['}' '{of']]
```

but instead it is:

```
[['!' '!']
 ['! ! !' '! ! ! !']
 ['! ! !' '! ! ! "']
 ['! ! !' '! ! ! .']
 ['}' 'was postponed']
 ['}' 'was']
 ['}' '{of']]
```

or something to that effect.

Comment: Can you give Python code for `arr1` and `arr2` that can be copied and pasted into a terminal or editor?

Comment: Sure just something representative and ideally the output you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand the format of your input, but you can adapt this to suit your needs.

The problem is that `numpy.intersect1d()` automatically sorts the output, for some reason. Luckily it's not that hard to write your own intersection function using `numpy.in1d()`. You can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([['! ! !' '! ! ! !'],
 ['! ! !' '! ! ! "'],
 ['! ! !' '! ! ! .'],
 ['!' '!'],
 ['a' 'ad'],   # Stuff you don't want to get back
 ['}' 'was postponed'],
 ['}' 'was'],
 ['}' '{of']])

arr2 = np.array([['! ! !' '! ! ! !'],
 ['! ! !' '! ! ! "'],
 ['! ! !' '! ! ! .'],
 ['!' '!'],
 ['b' 'ab'],   # Stuff you don't want to get back
 ['}' 'was postponed'],
 ['}' 'was'],
 ['}' '{of']])

inarr = np.in1d(arr1, arr2)

arr3 = np.empty( shape=(0, 0) )

for i in np.arange(len(arr1)):
  if (inarr[i]):
    arr3 = np.append(arr3,arr1[i])

for i in np.arange(len(arr3)):
  print(arr3[i])
```

The output:

```
! ! !! ! ! !
! ! !! ! ! "
! ! !! ! ! .
!!
}was postponed
}was
}{of
```